# Can the same Scala source file be compiled into class files containing different @ScalaSignature annotations?

Tags: scala

I've got two class files that I'm trying to prove were generated from the very same Scala source.

Upon decompiling the class files into Java I got two Java files that are exactly equivalent semantically. However they have different @ScalaSignature annotations inside them. I got the following outputs upon running "javap -verbose" on the class files:

```
...
SourceFile: "ABC.scala"
ScalaSig: length = 0x3
 05 00 00
Signature: #140                         // <T:Ljava/lang/Object;>Lcom/xyz/ABC;Lscala/ScalaObject;Lscala/Product;
Lscala/Serializable;
RuntimeVisibleAnnotations:
  0: #141(#142=s#143)
minor version: 0
major version: 49
flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_SUPER
---
```

from one file, and from the other:

```
...
SourceFile: "ABC.scala"
ScalaSig: length = 0x3
 05 00 00
Signature: #140                         // <T:Ljava/lang/Object;>Lcom/xyz/ABC;Lscala/ScalaObject;Lscala/Product;
Lscala/Serializable;
RuntimeVisibleAnnotations:
  0: #141(#142=s#143)
minor version: 0
major version: 49
flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_SUPER
...
```

Is it possible for the two class files to have been obtained from the same Scala source, be annotated with the same ScalaSig, Signature, etc., and yet have different @ScalaSignature annotations?

Thanks.

Comment: Haven't looked into the asm u post but in your place i'd ask about compiler versions. Specially if some of these versions were in the dev branch.

Comment: Thanks Pedro... pretty sure no dev branch compilers were used, just different final versions of the Scala compiler.

Comment: I only mentioned the dev branch because if you are working with trunk it's easy to forget that every time some code is committed into the compiler you are dealing with new compiler version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible for two scala source files to end up with the same byte code (except for the sig). Indeed, it's the sig that tells you that the original source files were different. So no, it's not possible to prove that two class files came from the same scala source.

For instance, if two classes have the same methods but with different type parameters, then you'd get the same bytecode, but different sigs.

As a trivial example, look at the following class:

```
class Foo {
  def fn1(t: String) = "" + t
  def fn2[T <: String](t : T) = "" + t
}
```

These two methods have exactly the same byte code generated, but the sigs will be different:

```
public java.lang.String fn1(java.lang.String);
  Code:
   Stack=1, Locals=2, Args_size=2
   0:   aload_1
   1:   invokestatic    #12; //Method java/lang/String.valueOf:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/String;
   4:   areturn
  LineNumberTable:
   line 2: 0

  LocalVariableTable:
   Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
   0      5      0    this       LFoo;
   0      5      1    t       Ljava/lang/String;

  Signature: length = 0x2
   00 12

public java.lang.String fn2(java.lang.String);
  Code:
   Stack=1, Locals=2, Args_size=2
   0:   aload_1
   1:   invokestatic    #12; //Method java/lang/String.valueOf:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/String;
   4:   areturn
  LineNumberTable:
   line 3: 0

  LocalVariableTable:
   Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
   0      5      0    this       LFoo;
   0      5      1    t       Ljava/lang/String;
```

Comment: +1 for the insight, but the OP is asking for the opposite: can the same source file, compiled several times, yield class files with different ScalaSignature. Or in other words, is there some mon-determinism in the compiler?

Comment: Right Régis, in particular, I'm wondering if using a different version of the maven scala plugin, or the scala-library.jar can cause the very same Scala source to get compiled into class files containing different @ScalaSignature annotations. Sorry for my post being unclear; I wasn't thinking about non-determinism though, though knowing whether non-determinism can be ruled out would be good to know.

Comment: @scala_is_awesome The answer to that is yes. Different versions of the scala compiler will store different data. I don't know exactly what gets stored, but it is by definition version specific. I wouldn't count on it.

Comment: Thanks Matthew! Could you also rule out the non-determinism aspect that Régis brought up? I haven't seen any non-determinism though. Had hoped the ScalaSignature annotations would stay stable if the Scala compiler version is changed as long as the Scala code being compiled stayed the same. Would you be able to comment on what happens if different parts of a Scala application's codebase are compiled with different Scala compiler versions? Could it have an impact on the application's performance, or cause issues during debugging (eg. breakpoints not hit, signal 5 thrown unexpectedly etc)?

Comment: Thanks in advance and sorry for asking so many questions... let me know if I should post separate questions...

Comment: If the file is compiled with the same version under the same circumstances, then it shouldn't be different. The ScalaSig isn't actually used when executing, so shouldn't have any impact at all on performance